# How to break long lines in grakn console?

Tags: vaticle-typedb, vaticle-typeql

Is there a kind of soft-break or line-continuation character for breaking longer lines into 2 or more short lines before submitting a graql statement?
Found nothing about this issue in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `editor` command to open your default editor (normally `vim`) and prepare multi-line queries there.